# XGBoost incremental training for big datasets

Tags: xgboost, training, bigdata

I am trying to train an XGBoost model on a quite big dataset (tens of GB, almost a hundred).

I have been trying to use some libraries such as Dask to deal with this problem, without any success due to high memory consumption (I opened a question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345302/reduce-dask-xgboost-memory-consumption), if you can answer, you are welcome).

Due to the above failure, I decided to implement my own incremental XGBoost training, something like what has been proposed here: [XGBoost incremental training](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079853/how-can-i-implement-incremental-training-for-xgboost)

The main idea is basically the following code:

```
params = {} # your params here
ith_batch = 0
n_batches = 100
model = None
while ith_batch < n_batches:
    d_train = getBatchData(ith_batch)
    model = xgb.train(params, d_train, xgb_model=model)
    ith_batch += 1
```

However I have three important questions:

1. Is this method of incremental training the same as training on the whole dataset? If not, why?
2. How should I split my batches at each iteration? Should I basically sweep the whole dataset sequentially?
3. How do the most common distributed/parallel compute libraries (Dask-ML, SparkML ecc...) train these models without storing everything in memory? Do they rely on incremental training?

Comment: Spark works in memory, but because it is distributed it utilizes memory of each core. Nevertheless some algorithms can't work in distributed manner.

Comment: @tkarahan Do you have any info on dask_ml? It should be able to deal with big data without loading everything to memory. However, from my many experiments, it seems that it behaves in the same way as Spark ML

Comment: I have no sufficient info about that, sorry. It's an important tool, in my learning list too. :)

Comment: No problems! Let's wait for someone who knows more about that

Comment: @MattiaSurricchio did you find a solution for that? I am confronted with the same problem.

Comment: @HerrDerb In the meanwhile some papers were published where they basically emulate the XGBoost behaviour with neural networks, allowing for incremental/batch learning. Standard XGBoost doesn't support batch training (because of the underlying mathematical model) and the incremental training I tried (this has not been methematically verified, but it's my intuition) is not equivalent to train the model on the whole data.

Comment: This is because of the mathematical model we're using. In neural networks, iterative batch training updates the weights of the model -> you're training the model "as a whole". In XGboost, with the iterative hack I proposed, what you're doing is start from a trained model and ADD other boosters to the model using new data. The original model is left untouched in this case (while neural networks updates their weights). I don't have a solid proof (performance or mathematical) of full training vs iterative training in XGBoost, but im confident enough to say they're NOT equivalent

Comment: But I can't strictly quantify such difference at the moment